# Angular2 pass referenced parameters between components

Tags: angular, parameters, components, interaction, two-way

I think this question isn't new for someone but I didn't find a simply solution.
I have 2 components, a parent that defines an object 'x' with inside another object 'y' (x.y).
It passes the object 'y' to the child

```
<child [obj]="x.y"></child>
```

Suppose that into the child component I have an input text that edit y.myStr.
When I change this value, from the parent component the value of x.y.myStr didn't change.

Why this? I read that object and array are passed by reference.

Could someone help me?

Thanks 
Fabrizio

Comment: Do use the default change detection strategy or did you modify it?

Comment: Only "@Input()" on children is used

Comment: Strange. My guess will be that it uses pass by value. Can you try [obj]="x" and then set the model of your input to "x.y"?

Comment: I tried to pass another object, and it seems to lost the reference after the children changes his value

Comment: Mmmm is it possible that the problem is a new assignment to the variable inside the children component?

Comment: It might, but if you pass and object and assign a field it should work